# Reading data from url where html page doesn't display it

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I am trying the following code:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = "https://bibles.org/bible/555fef9a6cb31151-01/3JN.1"
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    s = requests.session()
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

But I am not able to see the content of webpage. How do I extract them?

Answer (score 0):

You can only scrape what you see in the page source (go to `view-source:https://bibles.org/bible/555fef9a6cb31151-01/3JN.1`) using requests + bs4.

The page you're trying to scrape is a dynamic web app that loads text afterwards using JS + XHR. This means you need a browser + selenium[0] to load the page, and execute whatever JS it needs to load the content. When the page content is populated, you can get the actual HTML, and use bs4 to extract the text.

So, read up on how to use Selenium with python for scraping. You will need to use waits[1] as well to wait the right amount until the page reaches the state you want (the text is added to the page).

- [0] https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
- [1] https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html